# A monomial ideal, $I =\langle xy, xz, yz\rangle$, is radical

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

I need help in showing that $I =\langle xy, xz, yz\rangle$ is a radical ideal.

Thanks

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58845/radical-ideal-of-x-y2 (see comment by Leon Lampret)

Answer (score 3):

Book: *Monomial Ideals* by *Herzog-Hibi*

[image]